# this function return pagination on localhost but when i upload on my site pagination not working there

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

```
    function get_product_detail(){
    global $woocommerce, $wpdb, $current_user;
    $user =  $current_user->ID;
```

> Query i am using for data show

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` wpmeta INNER JOIN `$wpdb->posts` wp ON wpmeta.`post_id`=wp.`ID`  WHERE wpmeta.`meta_value`='".$current_user->ID."'
    AND wpmeta.`meta_key`='_customer_user' AND wp.`post_type`='shop_order' AND wp.`post_status`='wc-processing' GROUP BY wp.`ID`";
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
                $applct_name = $_REQUEST['applct_name'];
                $applct_email = $_REQUEST['applct_email'];
                $applct_msg = $_REQUEST['applct_msg'];
                $product_name = $_REQUEST['product_name'];
                $product_number = $_REQUEST['product_number'];
                 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
                $usermeta = array(
                        'name'=> $applct_name, 
                        'email'=>$applct_email, 
                        'product_name'=>$product_name, 
                        'message'=>$applct_msg
                        );

```
            $flag = 0;
            if($flag==0){
            add_user_meta($user, 'applicant_invite_by', $usermeta);


$headers = 'From: Backcheckgroup.com <noreply@backcheckgroup.com>' . "\r\n";
            wp_mail( $applct_email, 'Verfication Required', $applct_msg, $headers);
            $flag=1;
            echo 'Form submited';
            }else{

                echo 'Already submited';
                }
        }
    echo '<table class="order_detail">';
    echo '<tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>invite user</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr><tbody>';
```

> pagination start from here

```
    $query = $wpdb->query($sql);
    $total = $query;
    $items_per_page = 3;
    $page = isset( $_GET['cpage'] ) ? abs( (int) $_GET['cpage'] ) : 1;
    $offset = ( $page * $items_per_page ) - $items_per_page;

    $service = $wpdb->get_results( $sql . " LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$items_per_page."" );


    foreach( $service as $results ) {

          $orderID = $results->post_id; 
            $order          = new WC_Order($orderID); 
            $status         = $order->status;

            $order_items    = $order->get_items(); 


            if(count($order_items))
            {
                $j=1;
                foreach($order_items as $item){

                    $item_name          = $item['name'];
                    $product_id         = $item['product_id'];
                    $qty                = $item['qty'];

                    echo '<tr class="collaps"><th><span>+</span></th><th>'.$product_id.'</th><th>'.$current_user->billing_first_name.' / '.$current_user->billing_company.'</th><th>Invited(0/'.$qty.')</th><th>Completed(0/'.$qty.')</th></tr>';
                    for($i=1; $i <=$qty; $i++){
                         $numbers = rand(0,100);
                        echo  '<tr class="sub-rows"><td>'.$j.'</td>';   
                        echo '<td>'.$product_id.'</td>';    
                        echo '<td>'.$item_name.'</td>'; 



    echo '<td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_'.$numbers.'">invite</a></td>';


                            popup($numbers,  $qty, $item_name,  $user, $product_id);
                        $j++;
                            echo '<td>'.$status.'</td></tr>';   
                    }   


                } 

            } 
        } 
         echo '</tbody></table>';
```

> pagination printed here

```
  echo 'Pagination'.paginate_links( array(
        'base' => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
        'format' => '',
        'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
        'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
        'total' => ceil($total / $items_per_page),
        'current' => $page
    ));
        return $data; 
    }
```

Comment: i have print all variables it is shows value

Comment: can you please explain Conrad Lotz

Comment: I would assume that the authentication credentials on you local PC and on the host server would be different. i.e. the database host, user and password?

Comment: but  same function displaying listing on the site, only pagination is not working,